# IOS app when open onesignal notification, it will crash

Tags: ios, onesignal

my app added the `OneSignal` follow this guide: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

It works for sending and receiving messages, but for receiving the notification, if the app still work in background, it will not crash, otherwise, if the app closed, and if I click the notification, it will crashed. how can I fix it? 
and how can i check what's wrong? thanks so much !!!